# How to access an inherited anonymous pipe HANDLE, other than stdout, stderr & stdin, in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, ipc, child-process

I am trying to receive data from a child process over an anonymous pipe in Windows.  I know how to do this using standard I/O streams but these are being used for other purposes.  I also know how to do this in Linux or OSX using `fork()`, `pipe()` and `execv()`.

In Windows, you can create a pipe with `CreatePipe()` and make one end *not* inheritable with `SetHandleInformation()`.  Then for stdout and stderr you can pass `STARTUPINFO`, with `hStdOutput` or `hStdError` set, to `CreateProcess()` to pass the other end to the child.  After the call to `CreateProcess()` the parent most close it's handle to the child's end of the pipe.  This is all explained in detail in [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.  However, I have not found a way to pass a `HANDLE`, other than via stderr, stdout or stdin, to the child.

I've tried converting the `HANDLE` to a string with something like this:

```
std::ostringstream str;
str << hex << "0x" << handle;
std::string handleArg = str.str();
```

And then passing it as a command line argument and converting it back to a `HANDLE`, which is just a `void *` in the child process.  Although the child process apparently inherits the pipe `HANDLE` the actual value of the `HANDLE` must be different than in the parent because passing it this way fails to work.

I know I can use a named pipe to do this but it seems it should be possible to do this with anonymous pipes.

So how can I pass a pipe `HANDLE` to a child process in Windows?

**Update1:** Sample code in [this MSDN article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150523) seems to indicate that, at least with socket handles, you can pass them as a string to the child.

**Update2:** Turns out I made a mistake.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out you *can* pass a `HANDLE` to a child process as a command line argument by converting it to string and then, in the child process, back to a `HANDLE` (which is just a `void *`).  Sample code using a `HANDLE` to a socket can be [found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150523).

To make this work you need to make sure you follow [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) closely.  It's important that you close the child process's end of the pipe after calling `CreateProcess()` and get all the inheritance settings right.

Note, I tried passing the `HANDLE` as a string on the command line before but I was doing it wrong.  My mistake was in passing the `HANDLE` as an `int` to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor()` which made it treat it as a file descriptor instead of a Windows `HANDLE`.

Comment: It would be nice, if you would at least describe the principle as links frequently become invalid over time.
As I understand it, one must print the pointer as integer to string, write it to stdin of the child, parse it inside the child process as integer and convert it back to pointer that is representing the HANDLE.

Comment: I can confirm that this just works.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the method shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/pipe-handle-inheritance)?

> Call the GetStdHandle function to get the current standard output
> handle;  save this handle so you can restore the original standard
> output handle  after the child process has been created.
>
> Call the SetStdHandle function to set the standard output handle  to
> the write handle to the pipe. Now the parent process can create  the
> child process.
>
> Call the CloseHandle function to close the write handle to the pipe.
> After the child process inherits the write handle, the parent process
> no longer needs its copy.
>
> Call SetStdHandle to restore the original standard output handle.

Comment: The question is specifically about passing handles other than the standard ones.  Those functions are for the standard handles.  Thus the "Std" in their names.